# How should I download a pdf using python requests when the content comes back in a json object?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, python-requests

I'm trying to download a pdf using the requests library and after I do the post request I get a json object back. The json is formatted like so

```
{content: 'all_of_the_content',
contentType: 'application/pdf',
fileName: 'the_name_of_the_file.pdf'}
```

The content is about 388000 bytes. How should I save the content into a pdf file? So far I've tried

```
with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(response.json()['content'], 'utf-8'))

with open('file.pdf', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.json()['content'])

# These were desperation
with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

with open('file.pdf', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Possible helpful information. The json that comes back is identical to the json that comes back when looking at the response in chrome dev tools and the actual error that adobe throws is "Could not open file. It is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn’t correctly decoded)"
[image: Snip of response preview after post request. Left out fileName due to privacy concerns]

Comment: Your third attempt works for me, FWIW.

Comment: response.content is the json object as bytes like so `b{content: 'content', contentType: 'application/pdf', fileName: 'filename.pdf'}`

Comment: Oh, mine is a long string of bytes.

Comment: Yeah. That's my issue. I have no problem when it's just the content that comes back but in this case it's a json with the content contained within it.

Comment: It's not actually a JSON object. In `response.content` are just bytes. Those are what should be written to the file.

Comment: It seems to me the issue is that your URL is not to an actual PDF file.

Comment: Yes but in this case response.content is a json object as bytes.

Comment: It's not to an actual pdf file. How the website does it is a post request to their api with the document id. This is the response that gets returned.

Comment: Ah, so can you issue the POST request yourself? And get the response to *that* into the file?

Comment: Yeah. I am issuing the POST request and getting the response seen in the image above. I can't figure out how to get the content into a file. I thought one of the ways I tried would be successful but obviously they were not. It's the first time I've ever seen PDF content returned in this fashion and can't seem to find anything helpful in any language to get it saved

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out it's in a `base64` encoding. So first I had to convert the content string to bytes and then decode it using the `codec`s module.

```
content = bytes(response.json()['content'], 'utf-8')
with open("test.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(codecs.decode(content, "base64"))
```

Check your encodings!